# get component output in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

i'm building a component in joomla 2.5
In this component i need to get the display of other components (for example the body of an article). I have the url of these components, with get parameters.

I'm thinking of getting the whole page using the url and cUrl, but is there a better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful tutorial on this. It's still pretty complicated (at least for me, as Joomla as no clear support for loading multiple components in a single page).

http://www.ducciogasparri.com/2012/04/15/joomla-loading-multiple-components-in-a-single-page/

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to scrape data the way you suggest, this should never be done especially when the data you need already exists locally. You can use Joomla code, something like this:

```
$article = JTable::getInstance('content');
$article->load($article_id);
echo $article->get('fulltext');
```

Just replace $article_id with the ID of the article. And you can replace fulltext with the field that you want.

Comment: The problem is that I need several different components, and the only way to get the right view is using the display method of the controller...how can i call it from another controller?